# How do you compute the span of a $3\times1$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

How do you compute the span of a $3\times 1$ matrix?

For example:

> Compute the span of 
>   $\begin{bmatrix} 4\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\4 \end{bmatrix}.$

Comment: I would think the span of a single vector is simply the line it makes within it's $d$-dimensional space (in this case $3$).

Comment: Question has been updated

Comment: The span of two linearly independent vectors is a plane in this case

Comment: how to compute them?

Comment: There is nothing to compute, apart from noting that the two given vectors are linearly independent. Just apply the definition of span to the given data.

Answer (score 0):

The span by definition is the set of all linear combinations of an element (or set of elements) in a vector space. Call that matrix $m$

In this case take $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $Span_{\mathbb{R}}(m) = a*m$.

In general, you need to define over which subspace you are spanning, i.e. taking the coefficients, which in this case is only $a$.

Comment: Then span of a vector is a set.  I would instead write $span(m)=\{a\cdot m~:~a\in\Bbb F\}$ where $\Bbb F$ is whatever scalar field you are working with.

Comment: so here $\begin{bmatrix} 1/4\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix}$ will work but these are linearly independant right?

Answer (score 0):

The span of any basis element $v$ is just $av$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$. So the span is just all multiples of your vector.
$$
Span(v)=\{a \in \mathbb{R}|a
\begin{bmatrix}
4\\
0\\
1\\
\end{bmatrix}\}
$$

Comment: so the span is 4a + 0 + a = 5a?

Comment: The basic elements are vectors, so $Span(v)$ consists of all vectors with $a$ multiplying the vector. As an example, take $a=2$, then you have that $\begin{bmatrix}8\\0\\2 \end{bmatrix}$ is an element in $Span(v)$.

Comment: They doint tell me what $a$ is so would the answer then just be $\begin{bmatrix} 4a\\0\\a \end{bmatrix}$ ?

Comment: The span of something is not just one object, it is a collection of objects. In this case you are correct, the span is the collection of objects satisfying $\begin{bmatrix}4a\\0\\a \end{bmatrix}$, with $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: then what woulkd be its "geometric description " ? What do they mean by that

Comment: I updated my question as well

Comment: Try this, draw the vector [1,1], also draw the vectors you obtain when you multiply the given one by various real numbers. As you draw more of them what geometric shape do they start to form.

Answer (score 0):

The parametric form of the plane is $\{s(4,0,1)+t(6,3,15):s,t\in\mathbb{R}\}$.
Perhaps they want the form $\{(x,y,z):ax+by+cz=0\}$, and they want you to find a,b and c.
Let $a=1$, then use the fact that $(4,0,1)$ and $(6,3,15)$ are in the plane to find $b$ and $c$.

Comment: Yes, but how do i go about that?

Comment: If $(x,y,z)=(3,2,5)$ were in the plane, then $3a+2b+5c=0$.  I said $a=1$, so $2b+5c=-3$.  That is an equation in $b$ and $c$.  You have two different points, so you have two different equations in $b$ and $c$.

Comment: It says to compute the span... So that is all I do??

Comment: Yeah I don't understand what you're saying at all. They  are asking me to compute the span