# Computing the span

Tags: linear-algebra

> Compute the span of $\begin{bmatrix} 4\\2\\10 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 6\\3\\15 \end{bmatrix}$

I just don't even understand what "*Compute the span*" is even asking me. Can anyone give me a similar example so I can mimic it?

Comment: I believe it means, "Give the set $S$ that is spanned by these two vectors."

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Normally it is the set of all linear combinations of the two, but there is something you need to notice about the two vectors first.

Comment: First one is multiples of 2, second one is multipels of 3.. ok now what?

Comment: So they are not linearly independent, in fact they are each a multiple of the same vector.

Comment: This is, in essence, the same question as [what you asked a short while ago](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832804/how-do-you-compute-the-span-of-a-3x1-matrix).  The end result is again that you should understand the [definition of a span of vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span).  The easy answer is that if you have vectors $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$ the span of the vectors is the set of all possible linear combinations of the vectors.  In some cases you prefer to simplify things by removing redundancies or writing them in a convenient fashion.

Comment: If you have two non-parallel vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ then their span is the set of all linear combinations $sv_1+tv_2$ of the two vectors. But if the two vectors are parallel, then the span is just all the multiples of one of the vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meaning of Span of two vectors is all possible vectors made by the those basis vectors. Eg. let $v=span\{ v_1,v_2\}$, then $v=c_1v_1+c_2v_2$ where $c_1,c_2$ are Real no's. But while spanning two or more vectors, make sure that they should be linealy independent.

In your case, span{ $
        \begin{bmatrix}
        4 \\
        2 \\
        10 \\
        \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
        6 \\
        3 \\
        15 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$} = $c$$\begin{bmatrix}
        2 \\
        1 \\
        5 \\
        \end{bmatrix} $ , where $c$ is any real number
You can clearly see that both of the vectors can be formed using the third vector. By putting $c=2$, you will get first vector and $c=3$, you will get second. This is the final answer.

May be, this can help you in understanding the span.

Comment: No shammy, they are asking for which subspace of $R^3$ you can get only using those 2 vectors, as it turns out its just that line

Answer (score 1):

Hint $$\begin{bmatrix} 4\\2\\10 \end{bmatrix}  = \frac{2}{3}\begin{bmatrix} 6\\3\\15 \end{bmatrix}$$

EDIT: Since $\begin{bmatrix} 4\\2\\10 \end{bmatrix} and\begin{bmatrix} 6\\3\\15 \end{bmatrix}$ are linearly dependent, by the definition of span:

For all $\lambda$, $\mu \in R$

The span of these vector is  $\lambda\begin{bmatrix} 4\\2\\10 \end{bmatrix}+ \mu \begin{bmatrix} 6\\3\\15 \end{bmatrix}$ = $\lambda\begin{bmatrix} 4\\2\\10 \end{bmatrix}+ \frac{2\mu}{3} \begin{bmatrix} 4\\2\\10 \end{bmatrix}$ = $(\lambda+ \frac{2\mu}{3} )\begin{bmatrix} 4\\2\\10 \end{bmatrix}$

Let U = $(\lambda+ \frac{2\mu}{3} ) \in R$ so the span {U$\times\begin{bmatrix} 4\\2\\10 \end{bmatrix}$}

Comment: The answer is 2/3 ?

Comment: Of course not coz this is a hint

Comment: it shows that these two vector is not linear independent

Comment: Here is the definition of  span :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span#Definition

Comment: @Shammy there isn't any "formula."  Linear algebra and higher maths than that are not about "formulas," they are about definitions and concepts and understanding those definitions and concepts.  Perhaps [a video explanation](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors-and-spaces/linear-combinations/v/linear-combinations-and-span) will help you.